# Can't ping service inside Docker container from the host machine

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm running a container via `docker-compose` on Ubuntu 20.04, and I can't ping or curl the web server that's running inside from the host machine that's running docker.

I've given the container a static IP, and if I open a shell in the container I can see the service running fine and curl it as expected.

My docker-compose.yml looks like this:

```
version: "2.1"
services:
  container:
    image: imagename
    container_name: container
    networks:
      net:
        ipv4_address: 172.20.0.5
    environment:
      - PUID=1000
      - PGID=1000
      - TZ=Europe/London
    ports:
      - 9000:9000
    restart: unless-stopped

networks:
  net:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
     config:
       - subnet: 172.20.0.0/16
         gateway: 172.20.0.1
```

But if I `curl -v 172.20.0.5:9000` from the same machine, I get

```
*   Trying 172.20.0.5:9000...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* connect to 172.20.0.5 port 9000 failed: No route to host
* Failed to connect to 172.20.0.5 port 9000: No route to host
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.20.0.5 port 9000: No route to host
```

My best guess is something to do with iptables or firewall rules? I've not changed those at all from the default Docker set up. With `host` network mode it does work, but exposes the 9000 port publicly. I want to have it only accessible locally and then set it up behind a reverse proxy. Thanks.

Comment: Something is amiss here: your `curl` command is using port 9000, but the error you show is for port 9117.

Comment: You really should let docker manage the network rather than defining IPs yourself. I've yet to see a use case for defining static IPs, what is yours?

Comment: @larsks Oops copy paste error sorry, I was trying different ports to see if it had an effect.

Comment: @im_baby I've got a web server running on the machine that's not in docker, and want to reverse proxy a subdomain on that into the docker container. Assumed I'd need a static IP for the proxy to be able to reference the container.

Comment: The container-private IP addresses aren't accessible, except in one very specific host/OS setup.  You should be able to use the host's IP address (or `localhost` if you're outside a container but on the same host) and the first `ports:` number 9000.  You can also remove all of the `networks:` blocks from the file.

Comment: @DavidMaze That only seems to work if I change the network mode of the container to `host` - then I can access {ip}:9000 from anywhere and it works. I don't want to do it that way though, I want to have the container only directly accessible on the server, and expose  it publicly with a reverse proxy that's already running.

Comment: You can set `ports: ['127.0.0.1:9000:9000']` and the published port won't be accessible from off-host.  You should not need host networking in normal operation.

Comment: (What process is running inside the container?  What you're describing sounds like the symptom of a process that only listens on 127.0.0.1, which in this context would be the container-private localhost address; even if you're restricting the external connectivity, the process inside the container needs to listen on 0.0.0.0.)

Comment: Hm, if I do that and try `curl 127.0.0.1:9000` from the host I get Connection Refused. `docker ps` shows `127.0.0.1:9000->9000/tcp`.

It's not an image I can edit so it might be that? I can `curl 0.0.0.0:9000` from inside the container and get the right response, and the startup log ends with `Now listening on: http://[::]:9000` but other than that I can't tell what it's listening on.

Answer (score 1):

The static IP you gave is within the network docker created. Your host is correctly telling you that it has no routes to that subnet. However you are binding the containers port 9000 to your host port 9000, thus you should be able to ping/curl `localhost:9000`. If that doesn't work your webserver may need to listen on on `0.0.0.0`

Comment: Trying `curl localhost:9000` (or 0.0.0.0) fails immediately with `Connection refused`.

Comment: When the container is running what is the output of `docker ps`?

Comment: `5a96c198d9fb   image   "/init"   2 seconds ago   Up 1 second   0.0.0.0:9000->9000/tcp, :::9000->9000/tcp   container`

Actually just tried that curl again - this time it hung for a second then `Connection reset by peer`. Doesn't do that without the static IP

Comment: You should get rid of the static IP configs as mentioned by another commenter. What IP/port is the webserver inside the container listening on?

Comment: Port 9000. If I open a shell in the container I can `curl 0.0.0.0:9000` and get the response I expect.